# update query in postgresql using nodejs

Tags: node.js, postgresql

**Update student**

```
function update_student(req, student, next, res) {
    console.log('----',student);
   if (Object.keys(student).length > 0) {
       var query = updateQuery('student', req, student, '_id');
       var update_data = [];
       Object.keys(student).forEach(function(key) {
           update_data.push(student[key])
       });
       db.query(req, update_data).then(function(result) {
           return res.send('Updated');
           })
       }

   else {
       return res.send('nothing to update');
   }
};
```

**Update query**

```
function updateQuery(tablename, id, data, condition) {
   var query = ['UPDATE'];
   query.push(tablename)
   query.push('SET');
   var set = [];
   Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key, i) {
       if ((key == 'university_id') || (key == 'name') || (key == 'branch') || (key == 'age') || (key == 'email')) {
           set.push('"' + key + '"' + ' = $' + (i + 1));
       } else {
           set.push(key + ' = $' + (i + 1));
       }
   });
   query.push(set.join(', '));
   query.push('WHERE ' + condition + ' = ' + id);
   return query.join(' ');
}
```

What's wrong in the code? I am trying to write the update query in postgreSQL using node.js. I'm not able to update the student table using this query.

Comment: Are you getting any particular error, and have you tried printing out the generated query string to see if the generated Update even looks like valid SQL

Comment: You are supposed to add `.catch` handler to your `db.query` call, to process any error, which would tell you what's wrong with your query. It is shown in every example of using [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise).

Comment: It's showing 401 not found error in postman